# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 for OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I made a login jsp,
I am using Hibernate OneToOne annotation that for useradmin and wafat, 
class useradmin for login if there is for PK(useradmin) record in wafat is fine but when there is no PK(useradmin) record in wafat I got this error ~ 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

this my ERD ~

[image]

this is record from wafat table,

[image]

this is record from user table,

[image]

this is useradmin class,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserAdmin implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false)
private String no_dana;

@Column(name="npp")
private String npp;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Wafat wafat;

/**Setter and Getter Methods**/

}
```

this is my wafat class,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="wafat")
public class Wafat implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="kode_wafat", unique=true, nullable=false)
private String kode_wafat;

@Id
@JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
private String no_dana;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_wafat")

@Column(name="usia_wafat")
private Date tgl_wafat;

@Column(name="usia_wafat")
private int usia_wafat;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_makam")
private Date tgl_makam;

@Column(name="tempat_makam")
private String tempat_makam;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
private UserAdmin useradmin;

/**Setter and Getter Methods**/
}
```

this is ny login controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/afterlogin.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String directIndex(ModelMap model) {
    User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String sessionUser = user.getUsername();

    try {
        UserAdmin dataUser = userService.get(sessionUser);
        String userAuth = dataUser.getAuthority();
        System.out.println(userAuth);
        if(userAuth.equals("ROLE_ANGGOTA") || userAuth.equals("ROLE_PENGURUS")){
            return "redirect:/user/index.html";
        }
        else if(userAuth.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            return "redirect:/admin/index.html";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

this the error ~

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at org.ppbni.splatter.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.get(UserDaoImpl.java:33)
at org.ppbni.splatter.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.get(UserServiceImpl.java:21)
at org.ppbni.splatter.web.controller.LoginController.directIndex(LoginController.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is the part of my dao,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public UserAdmin get(String no_dana)throws Exception{

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserAdmin.class).add(Restrictions.eq("no_dana", no_dana));
    List<UserAdmin> userList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    return userList.get(0);

}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: The stack trace of the exception should tell you exactly where this exception is thrown. Read it, and post it.

Comment: As for the rest of the code: please reduce it to the relevant parts, i.e. if the problem is with one-to-one relation, all those other getters and setters aren't really necessary to be posted here - it clutters the question and makes it easy to overlook something.

Comment: Of course this is an issue when there is no record. You are trying to access the first one, if there isn't one, that is problematic.

Comment: for all, sorry.. i'll edit it ~

Comment: `at org.ppbni.splatter.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.get(UserDaoImpl.java:33)` - this imlies it's your dao that produces the error. Post the relevant parts of that (at least the method spanning across line 33) as well.

Comment: There you go: `userList.get(0)` - what happens if there is no user that matches the criteria? ... you get an exception.

Comment: @Thomas I think that shouldn't `return userList.get(0)`, right??

Comment: What to do depends on the rest of your application/style: if `userList` is empty you could throw an exception, return null (remember to handle it in the caller) or do whatever else is appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are adding `Restrictions.eq("no_dana", no_dana)` to your criteria chances are that there is no user matching that restriction. Hence calling `userList.get(0)` will result in said exception: it means you try to access the first index (0) out of zero indices (size 0) which clearly can't work.

To solve this you'll need to check the size of `userList` e.g. via `userList.isEmpty()` or `userList.size() > 0`.

What you do if there is no user depends on the rest of your application:

- you could return `null` in which case this would mean the user has not been found and you need to act accordingly
- you could directly throw an exception, preferably some named exception like `UserNotFoundException` etc., you then can either handle that in the caller or pass it all the way to the controller and display an appropriate message to the user
- create a new user (probably not, you'll most certainly want to keep control of which users are created and when)
- do something else (whatever is appropriate in your case)

**Update**

It seems like your mapping is wrong. From the edit it looks like `UserAdmin`and `Wafat` should be mapped using `no_dana`.  Hence I'd suggest `Wafat` to be the owning side of the relation with `no_dana` being the join column. This would mean that `wafat` in `UserAdmin` should be annotated with `@OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`. If there can be users without wafat you might want to add `optional=true` as well.

That way when there is no `Wafat` that references a `UserAdmin` instance the `wafat` field should be null when you load that `UserAdmin`.

Btw, `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` should be removed.

Comment: but the problem is the user that I looking is exist and still showing that error... i have table user and wafat that that bound with OneToOne annotation when user.no_dana is exist in the wafat.no_dana is fine but when user.no_dana is no exist in the wafat.no_dana it will showing that error ~

Comment: @splatter_fadli the error is still valid: your query doesn't return any user. The question thus is: why is the user not found? The problem seems to be that your mapping is wrong, both useradmin and wafat (what ever that is) claim to be the owning side of the relation but operate on different values. Add `mappedBy` to one of the `OneToOne` annotations and put the join property/column into the other entity.

Comment: i've edited my question, there are my ERD, record of user and wafat & make my class more simple to read :)

Comment: @splatter_fadli I added an update to my answer. Your mapping looks almost good, just remove `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` which is used for inheritance instead of relations and it should work.

Comment: whoaaahhh, just only because an annotation :)), thanks dude :DD

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<UserAdmin> userList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
 return userList.get(0);
```

add a  check on your `List`  :

```
List<UserAdmin> userList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);

if(userList!=null && !userList.isEmpty()){
  return userList.get(0);
}
// throw a custom Exception, IllegalArgumentException as an example here
throw new IllegalArgumentException("No user were found");
return null;
```

On your Controller:

```
 try {
        UserAdmin dataUser = userService.get(sessionUser);
        String userAuth = dataUser.getAuthority();
        System.out.println(userAuth);
        if(userAuth.equals("ROLE_ANGGOTA") || userAuth.equals("ROLE_PENGURUS")){
            return "redirect:/user/index.html";
        }
        else if(userAuth.equals("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            return "redirect:/admin/index.html";
        }
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
       //handle it properly here
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: but the problem is the user that I looking is exist and still showing that error ~

Comment: @splatter_fadli check the `ùserName` your querying with and make sure it exists on db

Comment: I've already check it and exist...  i have table user and wafat that that bound with OneToOne annotation when user.no_dana is exist in the wafat.no_dana is fine but when user.no_dana is no exist in the wafat.no_dana it will showing that error ~